# Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, directions

I am trying to get the driving direction between the two positions:

```
LatLng(12.917745600000000000,77.623788300000000000)
LatLng(12.842056800000000000,7.663096499999940000)
```

The code which i have tried:

```
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().
    add(new LatLng(12.917745600000000000,77.623788300000000000),
    new LatLng(12.842056800000000000,7.663096499999940000))
       .width(5).color(Color.RED));
```

But this draws a straight line between the two points .
Is there any other method/way to get the driving directions between these two points.

Comment: Side note: You can lose some of the digits at the end of the coordinates. You have specified the positions down to 1/10000000000 of a millimeter, which makes the coordinates wrong really fast, considering that the continental drift is in the range of 1/100000 millimeters per second...

Answer (score 150):

I just release my latest library for Google Maps Direction API on Android
https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Comment: please let me know more information about your "Sample Code" written on above. In my case, I can't get the polyline, just but a simple map.

Comment: +1, but for getDurationText() I get values that are way too small. Any help?

Comment: Hi, 
Document doc = builder.parse(in);
line is parsing only 1 line of the inputStream for the same code.
why?

Comment: What would work really well is if you made this to insert multiple locations and it finds the quickest path through those locations and navigates you through those. This way making it faster to visit multiple locations saving you fuel and time

Comment: @uofc I added it back for you.

Comment: My lastest code for Google Direction API  https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionAndPlaceLibrary

Comment: @Akexorcist I am getting null pointer exception error message by following the codes provided. Do you have any idea?

Comment: When i import this library i get this error (The method setFlat(boolean) is undefined for the type Marker) any idea what i need to do to make it support

Comment: @user2273146 Update your google play services library to latest version

Comment: @Akexorcist Hi, i'm getting a NullPointerException at  nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");  in your GMapV2Direction class, do you know why?

Comment: @Fondesa I'm not sure. I guess it doesn't contain with 'step' tag in xml data

Comment: Here is my demo project with API v21:

https://github.com/billypchan/AndroidMapTest

Comment: Hi everyone, I just updated my latest library. Change XML to JSON and using retrofit, gson and parceler. 

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Comment: I am getting "REQUEST_DENIED"-Callback, although my key is server key and activated?

Comment: @GaryKlasen I just updated latest version that you can check error message from API.

Comment: Its not drawing path,Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Akexorcist... your code is working fine if i have only start and end points.. what should i do to show waypoints in between?? help

Comment: I got an error D:\***\AndroidManifest.xml:56:9-58:47 Error:
 Element meta-data#com.google.android.geo.API_KEY at AndroidManifest.xml:56:9-58:47 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:30:9-32:71
D:\***\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
 Validation failed, exiting

Comment: @AlbertoM What's going on? I just updated my library in 2 months ago.

Answer (score 17):

This is what I am using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude_cur+","+longitude_cur+"&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );     
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is a web implementation I don't think this is what he is going for.

Comment: @Basim Sherif I tried this out but when it opens up the maps application the start point is always considered as the current location of device even though I provide a different location in 'saddr'. Can you please help me how do I avoid this?

Comment: @Zeba Can you please post your code? just needed intent part.

Comment: My device locale is Germany when I show the route in Google maps it shows latitude longitude in German units(',' instead of '.').Can We change that?? I need it in English language.

Comment: @JAPS : Convert your lat nd long to string, then replace "," with "." .Convert back into long.

Comment: @Basim Sherif : simple and effective solution ,this is great help.i would like to follow you for more android help .share your fb id please.

Comment: @Zeba just delete the spaces before saddr in the url!

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the following project that aims to help use that api. It's here:https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/GDirectionsApiUtils

How it works, definitly simply:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DCACallBack{
/**
 * Get the Google Direction between mDevice location and the touched location using the     Walk
 * @param point
 */
private void getDirections(LatLng point) {
     GDirectionsApiUtils.getDirection(this, mDeviceLatlong, point,     GDirectionsApiUtils.MODE_WALKING);
}

/*
 * The callback
 * When the direction is built from the google server and parsed, this method is called and give you the expected direction
 */
@Override
public void onDirectionLoaded(List<GDirection> directions) {        
    // Display the direction or use the DirectionsApiUtils
    for(GDirection direction:directions) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "onDirectionLoaded : Draw GDirections Called with path " + directions);
        GDirectionsApiUtils.drawGDirection(direction, mMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this -

```
val polyline1 = map?.addPolyline(
            PolylineOptions().clickable(true)
                .add(LatLng(23.8103, 90.4125), LatLng(4.0383, 21.7587))
                .geodesic(true)
        )
```