# Full implementation of Google Maps Directions Service on My Android App

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have searched for hours on the web for an example of implementing the direccions service on my android app.

```
I am using the google maps android api 2.
```

Basically I want the directions from the actual position and a marker position selected by the user.

I want to make clear that I don´t want to launch a web browser or the google maps aplication, I want to implement the service on my own app.

Till now I found some examples about drawing the route on tha map, which are ok

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/

[Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901)

so I just miss the indications part of the service so y can show on my own listview with arrows (turn to left , to right , etc).

Thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want. In your second link about Google Map API v2, the data for drawing maps comes from maps.googleapis.com .You can see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/ for more documentation about that.

The xml returned from maps.googleapis.com include `<html_instructions>` tag which contains instruction like `turn left` or `turn right`. So you just need to parse that xml and use `<html_instructions>` tag for information you need on your `listview`.

I hope this helps.