# How to draw a path between two points using mapFragment?

Tags: android, path, routes, google-maps-api-2, mapfragment

I want to now how to draw a path between tow points in mapFragment.
The first one is the user current position, and the second is pre-defined position.
After searching online, I found a lot of complex answers that consider as an Android Programming Professional!
Also, most of answers are based on API v1 that uses mapView to present the map which now is deprecated as I read.

What I have now is an activity with a mapFragment , and I can run my app and see the world on the map.

please , keep simple as you can :) .

Comment: whether you are using android map v2?

Comment: Try this it worked for me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901

Comment: thank you "Nitin Gupta" , I try it before asking. It self runs OK, but I don't know how to integrate it in my project, I get "Force close" every time the activity starts.

Comment: @user2330755 - first thing..can you run application successfully?i mean as you have mentioned you did get "Force close" every time.so i m asking.

Comment: yes , I can import the project shown in second comment, and run it in my mobile successfully, after that I try to copy its classes and XML to my app and modify my manifest file , then I install my app . the result is "Force Close" .

Comment: I capture the error from LogCat : http://s14.postimg.org/n2b3mujap/Log_Cat.png

Comment: The Link is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2). Surely this is useful to you.I get same thing as you need from this link. Hope this will help you too.