# Google maps api v2 get directions

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using google maps api v2 in android . I have placed a marker. How can i get directions between current location and the marker.Any help would be great.

Comment: There is nothing in Maps V2 (or Maps V1, for that matter) to give you directions.

Comment: so how to do it i know the location of marker how should i display directions from current location to the marker like we get directions when we us google maps on browser

Comment: @Ravi i think you want to display route between two points?Am i right?

Comment: Yes.exactly how to do it

Comment: check this code: https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this code I was provided here in one of the posts for creating Polyline from Google Direction API, you can change the class that gets the data if you want to get it from other source but this is how you do it. Create a class that will be responsible for getting the direction and parsing:

```
public class GMapV2Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public GMapV2Direction() { }

public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode="+ mode;

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
}
```

Create a getDirections `AsyncTask`:

```
public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object, ArrayList<LatLng>> {

public static final String USER_CURRENT_LAT = "user_current_lat";
public static final String USER_CURRENT_LONG = "user_current_long";
public static final String DESTINATION_LAT = "destination_lat";
public static final String DESTINATION_LONG = "destination_long";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
private MapFragmentActivity activity;
private String url;

private Exception exception;

private Dialog progressDialog;

public GetDirectionsAsyncTask(MapFragmentActivity activity /*String url*/) 
{
    super();
    this.activity = activity;

    //  this.url = url;
}

public void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = DialogUtils.createProgressDialog(activity, activity.getString(R.string.get_data_dialog_message));
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if (exception == null) {
        activity.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
    } else {
        processException();
    }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params) {

    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try{
        LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LONG)));
        LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LONG)));
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE));
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);
        return directionPoints;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

private void processException() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_when_retrieving_data), 3000).show();
}

}
```

In your `Activity` create those 2 methods:

```
public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints)
{
    Polyline newPolyline;
    GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
    {          
        rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
    }
    newPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}


public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

    GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this);
    asyncTask.execute(map); 
}
```

Finally run this method to create the `Polyline`:

```
findDirections(AppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                   AppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude(),
                                                   clickMarkerLatLng.latitude, clickMarkerLatLng.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
```

Comment: thanks for this code..but getDurationValue and getDistanceValue returns same values every time.

Comment: thanks for reply.I think i have to put more debug points.there must be some mistake.