# How to start with the implementation of navigation?

Tags: android, navigation, driving-directions

How to start implementation of navigation in my application?

I want to see route between source and destination (for walk, driving, bicycling) with turning points. Which is the best API?

Comment: have you tried any thing.?

Comment: yeah i tried gmapv2direction but only getting same direction for all mode:walk, drive. How to add turning points to it? I want it with more effective

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you take a look at the **Google Maps v2 Android API**:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Concerning Navigation, this could give you a hint:

```
Intent nav= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_LON,START_LAT&daddr=END_LON,END_LAT")); 
startActivity(nav);
```

Please also take a look at this (possible duplicate) post for a full example of **how to implement navigation and getting directions**:

[Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901)

For **getting started** with the Maps API, please read carefully through this document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Hehe was just writing the same thing :)

Comment: for me Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_LAT,START_LON&daddr=END_LAT,END_LON") only worked.