# Shortest path direction in Android

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2, shortest-path

I'm new in Google maps V2, i want to find the shortest path for my current location and the destination place. So, i tried some code and it works but it dose not draw the shortest path. i need a help please:

Here is my code:

```
gps = new GPSTracker(ViewOnMap.this);

// check if GPS enabled     
if(gps.canGetLocation()){

     latitude = gps.getLatitude();
     longitude = gps.getLongitude();
}
                LatLng origin = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                LatLng dest = new LatLng(lat,lon);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_on_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}
/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}


}
```

Thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053901/1991579). And use:

```
...
DirectonTask dirTask = new DirectonTask(this);
        dirTask.execute(md.getUrl(new LatLng(loc1.getLatitude(), loc1.getLongitude()), 
                new LatLng(loc2.getLatitude(), loc2.getLongitude(),GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING));
...
```

and method calling after task completed

```
GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
    Document doc;
    Polyline currentPath;
    public void drawDirection(Document doc) {
        this.doc = doc;
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(
                Color.RED);

        for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) 
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));

        map.addPolyline(rectLine);


}
```

GMapV2Direction.java:

```
public class GMapV2Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";
private static final String TAG = "google_map_GMapV2Direction";
public GMapV2Direction() { }

public String getUrl(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode){
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&mode="+mode;
    return url;
}
public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&mode="+mode;

    try {
        LOG.d(TAG, "url = "+url);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    LOG.i(TAG,"DurationText: "+ node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    LOG.i(TAG,"DurationValue: "+ node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    LOG.i(TAG,"DistanceText: "+ node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    LOG.i(TAG,"DistanceValue: " +node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    LOG.i(TAG,"StartAddress: "+node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    LOG.i(TAG,"StartAddress: "+node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    LOG.i(TAG,"CopyRights: "+node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
```

}

And DirectionTask:

```
public class DirectonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {
    private static final String TAG = "google_map_DirectonTask";
    Context c;
    MapGoogle map;
    public DirectonTask(MapGoogle map) {
        super();
        this.map = map;
//      this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute(); 

    }



    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... url) {
//      LOG.d(TAG, "url = " + url[0]);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        // HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url[0]);
            HttpResponse response;
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
        if (result != null) {

            map.drawDirection(result);

        } else {
            LOG.d("onPostExecute: direction = null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the logcat shows the error in :
    dirTask.execute(md.getUrl(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), new LatLng(lat, lon),GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING));