# NullPointerException in android studio google maps v2 project (Draw Route)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to create a route beetween two point in google maps android api v2.
I'm following a great and simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/get-driving-directions-using-google-maps-api-v2/15053901#15053901) in Stackoverflow.

I'm using android Studio template for google maps, I get an exception in the execution of my code but I don't know why, this is the error:

[image]

the lines that contains errors :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE :** I tried to change the call of this class but I still get the two first problems.

Comment: (1) Are you sure you are getting this exception during *compilation*, and not during execution? (2) Where is line 112 in your code?

Comment: I'm sorry it's a mistake , it's during the execution ! and the line 112 is in the first picture that have number 1 and is selected with yellow

Comment: In that case, see my very simple answer..

Comment: `doc` is `null`. Which means that `md.getDocument` is returning a `null` value.

Comment: yes but how can  I solve that problem ? because the class work for the others but me no. @Code-Guru

Comment: What is `md`? Where is it declared?

Comment: md is object of class GMapV2Direction , it's declared in onCreate() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setUpMap()` is passing a `null` value to `getDirection()`.

Comment: Thank you !  but what do you suggest to solve this problem please ?

Comment: So getDirection(); is the method that give me this error ? @cybersam

Comment: Yes. The stack trace says that the `NullPointerException` is occurring at line 112.