# Google map cluster with direction

Tags: android, google-maps

We have a [Google map library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) to show multiples markers in cluster.

I have two questions:

### 1. Can we show multiple Directions on Google map just like below image?

### 2. Can we show multiple direction details in cluster markers?

[image]

cluster is like below:

i will give you examples : fro country India i have save different directions in my db.

like

ahmedabad to delhi

Delhi to Agra

ahmedabad to bombay

jaypur to delhi

I have to show cluster of above directions depend on zoom level,
when user zoom Google map, instead of clusters there is multiple directions showing on Google Map.

I want to know if its possible? If yes then how?

Comment: do you want to show multiple directions as a cluster??

Comment: Do u have latitude & longitude of two points of a direction path. i.e (from,to).

Comment: So, am I understanding this correctly? 1) You want multiple direction lines shown on the map 2) If the direction lines are within a certain tolerance, they aren't to be rendered, but a cluster marker shown instead 3) If the cluster marker is clicked/hovered then... you want the directions to be shown?  Also, how have you retrieved the direction information?  Is it via the google directions API or some other source?

Comment: @GHC: please check question again...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal by using the Directions API. You supply the starting point and the ending point (it can be either lat/lon or name of the place). Another required field is the traveling mode (driving by default).

Now the Directions return the vertexes which can be transformed to a polyline and then drawn on the map. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053901) does that pretty well and I'll be using it's code.

```
package com.example.simon.maps;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;

/**
 * Created by Simon on 2014 Jul 25.
 */

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    final static String TAG = "MainActivity";
    GoogleMap mMap;
    GMapV2Direction md;
    int mZoomLevel;
    final float STARTING_ZOOM = 5.0f;
    // List of polylines for each zoom level
    SparseArray<List<Polyline>> mPolylines = new SparseArray<List<Polyline>>();

    public class direction {
        String start, end;
        int zoomLevel;

        direction(String pStart, String pEnd, int pZoomLevel) {
            start = pStart;
            end = pEnd;
            zoomLevel = pZoomLevel;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy p = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(p);
        }

        md = new GMapV2Direction();
        mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        List<direction> directions = new ArrayList<direction>();
        directions.add(new direction("Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India", "delhi,India", 4));
        directions.add(new direction("Ahmedabad,Gujarat,India","Bombay,Maharashtra,India", 4));
        directions.add(new direction("Jeypore,Odisha,India", "delhi,India", 5));
        for (MainActivity.direction direction : directions) {
            // Query
            Document doc = md.getDocument(direction.start, direction.end);
            // Parse the xml
            if (doc == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get the route from " + direction.start
                        + " to " + direction.end);
                continue;
            }
            // Get points
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
            // Convert vertexes to a polyline
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
            for (LatLng aDirectionPoint : directionPoint) {
                rectLine.add(aDirectionPoint);
            }
            // Add poly to the map
            addPolyline(rectLine, direction.zoomLevel);
        }
        // Get the starting point of the first direction
        LatLng start = mPolylines.valueAt(0).get(0).getPoints().get(0);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(start, STARTING_ZOOM), 1000, null);
        // Set the initial zoom level and show the necessary polylines
        mZoomLevel = (int) STARTING_ZOOM;
        initPolylines(mZoomLevel);

        // Listen for the camera zoom level changes
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                // Note that because we are casting the zoomLevel to int,
                // it will be considered as changed only when it reaches
                // a new integer when rounded (e.g. 5.0, 6.0 etc.)
                int newZoomLevel = (int) cameraPosition.zoom;
                if (newZoomLevel != mZoomLevel) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "New zoom level: " + newZoomLevel);
                    // Loop all the changed zoom levels
                    // E.g. zoomed-out from 15 to 13, then hide [14, 15]
                    if (newZoomLevel < mZoomLevel) { // Zoomed out
                        for (int i=1; i<=mZoomLevel-newZoomLevel; i++)
                            hidePolylines(mPolylines.get(newZoomLevel+i));
                    } else { // Zoomed-in
                        for (int i=1; i<=newZoomLevel-mZoomLevel; i++)
                            showPolylines(mPolylines.get(mZoomLevel + i));
                    }
                    mZoomLevel = newZoomLevel;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addPolyline(PolylineOptions polyOpts, int zoomLevel) {
        List<Polyline> polylines = mPolylines.get(zoomLevel);
        // Create polyline list for this zoom level, if it still doesn't exist
        if (polylines == null) {
            polylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
            mPolylines.put(zoomLevel, polylines);
        }
        // Append a new item to this poly list
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyOpts);
        polyline.setVisible(false);
        polylines.add(polyline);
    }

    private void initPolylines(int zoomLevel) {
        for(int i=0; i<mPolylines.size(); i++) {
            // Loop until zoom level is reached
            if  (mPolylines.keyAt(i) > zoomLevel) break;

            showPolylines(mPolylines.get(mPolylines.keyAt(i)));
        }
    }

    private void showPolylines(List<Polyline> polylines) {
        if (polylines != null)
            for (Polyline polyline : polylines) polyline.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void hidePolylines(List<Polyline> polylines) {
        if (polylines != null)
            for (Polyline polyline : polylines) polyline.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

This code adds the polylines to a SparseArray which holds the polylines for each zoom level. All polies are hidden by default and are revealed only when a specific zoom level is reached (also at `initPolylines`).

There are a few things to note here:

1. Because the **zoom can change by a few levels at once** we loop each level to hide/show specific directions.
2. The **location names have to be precise** or they won't be found and you might receive a bunch of errors in the code (I've only added a Log.e)
3. If you want to create **markers** at, let's say the starting and the ending point of the direction, you can use the following code to get the coordinates:

   ```
   List<LatLng> points = mPolylines.valueAt(0).get(0).getPoints();
   LatLng start = points.get(0);
   LatLng end = points.get(points.size()-1);
   ```
4. Markers can be added/removed at specific zoom levels just like it's done here with the polylines.

And here's the code of the xml parser (GMapV2Direction):

```
package com.example.simon.maps;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class GMapV2Direction {

    public GMapV2Direction() { }

    public Document getDocument(String start, String end) {
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin="+start+"&destination="+end+"&units=metric&mode=driving";
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            return builder.parse(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for (LatLng anArr : arr) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(anArr.latitude, anArr.longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
            if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```

Some final notes:

- If you've a lot of directions load them inside `initPolylines` and `showPolylines` and unload them in `hidePolylines`
- If the directions you want to show on the map are constant, the best way would be to use tiles with polylines on specific zoom levels. A good free tool for that is **Maperitive**, it can export the tiles to as many zoom levels as you want. Then you would store the tiles online and use UrlTileProvider to display them on your map.

Answer (score -1):

I dont't know if I understood your question correctly, but I'll try to answer anyway.
You can create multiple [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes) and add to map from the JSON response from [google maps direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). This way you can add several routes in a single map.

As far as I understood the second question, you want the cluster marker to give details of the routes you are drawing. For that, I guess you can cluster the points returned by the API and use [custom marker clusters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering) to show the info you want.

Hope it helps

-Edit-
If you want to draw routes in an Android app, you don't get any DirectionRenderer you can use. You need to render the routes using Polylines. That's why I have mentioned creating polylines in the answer above. As a response to the Direction request, you get a JSON containing several coordinate points which can be joined by drawing a polyline through them.
You can have multiple such polylines on a map (from any point to any point).
Case 1: you want 2 routes from Bombay to Goa, set the alternatives parameter to true.
Case 2: you want two different routes, Bangalore to Bombay, Goa to Delhi, make two different requests to the API. You'll get two different routes and draw them on map.

For your second question, since there is no inbuilt clustering for routes (polylines), you have to code the logic of cluster icons showing up in the map. For getting the current zoom level, use the following.

```
GoogleMap map;    
float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
```

For showing and hiding polylines

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
 .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))

 // multiple points that you get from the response of directions API

 .width(5)
 .color(Color.RED));

//your logic for visibility
if(zoom<=5){
  line.setVisible(true);
}
```

I couldn't find any way in the API to hide the cluster Icon using code. I guess it should hide itself after certain zoom level.

Comment: dont want multiple polilines, looking for multiple directions from one plase to another

Comment: If you check the link for directions API, it has an option 'alternatives' which if set to true, will provide multiple routes for from one point to another.

Comment: you have check attached image? how many directions are there?

Comment: In the attached image, you have shown 3 different routes, for which the original solution should work (creating polylines for the multiple routes you have) (You get the points of the routes by querying the google direction API). In the comments you said you wanted "multiple directions from a single place to another", that's why I replied with that solution. If this is not what you want, you should add a better description to the question.