# How to show two location on Google map which is enter by user and draw the route between them

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have two `EditText` where user enter two city name I want **draw route** between two city and distance between them on Google map.

Comment: get lat long of city enter by u and drow path beetween two latlang

Comment: You wan to show path using android default route application or your custom ?

Comment: how to get lat long of two city enter in edittext by their name...please naveen sir help me

Comment: @haresh sir i want to draw a rpute between city enter by user in two edittext

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Directions API to get the routes between them.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA

Then you can see the accepted answer here of how to encode the "points"-parameter to LatLng's / Polylines.

This should cover your question i guess:
[Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/get-driving-directions-using-google-maps-api-v2)

What you need to know to do this: How to do network requests, how to parse JSON, and how to setup a GoogleMap in your app.

Comment: how do i get lat long for two enter city in edittext by city name?