# REQUEST_DENIED in Google Maps Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get directions in an app, but I keep getting a `REQUEST_DENIED`, I am using the library mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/get-driving-directions-using-google-maps-api-v2/15053901#15053901) (And here [is the repo](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary))

I have the API key and I am using it like this:

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey(getString(R.strings.google_maps_key))
    .from(new LatLng(40.2085, -3.7136))
    .to(new LatLng(mCoord[0], mCoord[1]))
    .avoid(AvoidType.FERRIES)
    .avoid(AvoidType.HIGHWAYS)
    .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction) {
                if (direction.isOK()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DIRECTION KOK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //                            direction.
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), direction.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

I don't have any clue of what is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It is the first time I am using the google console developer, I thought I only needed the API key.

It turns out you have to activate the [Google Direction API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/directions_backend/overview?project=animated-zenith-120317).

Now the request is correct.