# Is there a way to show road directions in Google Map API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions, google-directions-api

I was looking for an answer using Google and here, and the only relevant posts I have found are:

[Google Maps Android V2 and Direction API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916679/google-maps-android-v2-and-direction-api)

[Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions)

but there is no answer there. So I have already mentioned it but I will say that again. I am looking for a solution for the Google Map API v2 using FragmentActivity and a SupportMagFragment and LatLng objects and not using MapView ,MapActivity and GeoPoint.

In addition I don't have the Overlay object to use so I can't paint the direction on the map, is there an alternative for that?

So is there a way to do that?

Comment: It looks like this question is answered entirely by another one. I suggest that this question is marked as a duplicate, to signpost future readers to the correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901). You can get driving or walking direction on V2.

Comment: Great one @Akexorcist, the only thing that you should add to this solution is that the "getDocument" method should be run in an Async-Task. this solution was tested by me and it works after making that change. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Overlay is indeed something to forget.

Polylines can easily be drawn

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines#add_a_polyline

Just loop through yourr points after you parsed tjhe JSON response:

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Set the rectangle's color to red
rectOptions.color(Color.RED);

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question title is much more general than your requirements, so I will answer this in a way that I think will benefit those viewing this question and hopefully meet your requirements in perhaps a different way.

If you are not showing directions in the context of a map already being a loaded fragment and something having been done to show directions over the map (which is probably similar to what the OP is doing), it's easier and I believe standard to do this with an `Intent`.

This launches a map pathing activity (through a separate application - where the app launched depends on the user's compatible apps, which by default is Google Maps) that plots directions from the origin address (`String originAddress`) to the 
destination address (`String destinationAddress`) via roadways:

```
// Build the URI query string.
String uriPath = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/";
// Format parameters according to documentation at:
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro
String uriParams = 
    "?api=1" +
    "&origin=" + originAddress.replace(" ", "+")
        .replace(",", "") +
    "&destination=" + destinationAddress.replace(" ", "+")
        .replace(",", "") +
    "&travelmode=driving";
Uri queryURI = Uri.parse(uriPath + uriParams);
// Open the map.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, queryURI);
startActivity(activity, intent, null);
```

(Where `activity` is simply the currently active `Activity` - obtained through whatever means are appropriate in the current programming context).

The following code gets an address `String` from a `LatLng` object (which must then be processed for the URI query `String` as above):

```
/**
* Retrieves an address `String` from a `LatLng` object.
*/
private void getAddressFromLocation(
    final StringBuilder address, final LatLng latlng) {
    // Create the URI query String.
    String uriPath = 
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
    String uriParams = 
        "?latlng=" + String.format("%f,%f",
            latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude) +
        "&key=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_WEB_API_KEY;
    String uriString = uriPath + uriParams;
    // Issue the query using the Volley library for networking.
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JSONObject response = null;
    // Required for JsonObjectRequest, but not important here.
    Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JsonObjectRequest request = 
        new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
            uriString,
            new JSONObject(jsonParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        if (response != null) {
                            String resultString =
                                response.getJSONArray("results")
                                        .getJSONObject(0)
                                        .getString("formatted_address");
                            // Assumes `address` was empty.
                            address.append(resultString);
                        } // end of if
                        // No response was received.
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // Most likely, an assumption about the JSON 
                        // structure was invalid.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } // end of `onResponse()`
            }, // end of `new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()`
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error occurred ", error);
                }
            });
    // Add the request to the request queue.
    // `VolleyRequestQueue` is a singleton containing
    // an instance of a Volley `RequestQueue`.
    VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(activity)
        .addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

This request is asynchronous, but [it can be made synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley).
You will need to call `toString()` on the actual parameter passed to `address` to obtain `originAddress`.

Answer (score -1):

> Q:I was looking for an answer using Google and here, and the only
>   relevant posts i have found are: Google Maps Android V2 and Direction
>   API Google map API v2 - get driving directions

**Answer:** Your saying, "but there is no answer there." is not absolutely right. In this site, you can find just only a few clues about that. I think you will not get the perfect code and concrete implement KNOW-HOWs here. In fact, many developers want to make the app to display the routing or directions on Google Maps. But I think there is no solution to get directions just only with the pure Google Maps API v2.

> Q: So I have already mentioned it but I will say that again. I am
>   looking for a solution for the Google Map API v2 using
>   FragmentActivity and a SupportMagFragment and LatLng objects and not
>   using MapView ,MapActivtiy and GeoPoint.

**Answer:** Here are [a few good sample tutorials (click here)](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/). You can find what you want.

> Q: In addition i don't have the Overlay object to use so i can't paint
>   the direction on the map, is there an alternative for that? So is
>   there a way to do that?

**Answer:** In the Google Maps API v2, the annoying Overlay and so on are not any more required. For this, you can find the answer in my linked site above.