# Google directions on OpenLayers

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, map-directions

I'm a big fan of OpenLayers. The only thing i'm missing here are directions.

Since google maps supports directions, I want to integrate these with OpenLayers.

Is it possible to use the google maps api to get directions from point A to point B (support for waypoints?) and then display on my map (as an extra vector layer?)?

Answer (score -1):

Google Maps doesn't support directions. and you have to use Google Directions API to get you direction instructions. as for displaying the directions on google maps, it's can be done. head to this post to

[first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554078/is-there-a-way-to-show-road-directions-in-google-map-api-v2)

or:

[second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901)

to read more.

Comment: I'm not searching for gmap directions integration on a google map, but as an openlayers vector layer. The linked posts both describe directions on a google map...

Comment: sorry, have no idea on how to use openlayers vector layer.