# Android:Draw path on mapv2 as device moves

Tags: android, google-maps

i am making an app in which i have to **draw path on map as my devices moves**. I searched my tutorials  **but all show to draw path b/w two points** but i want to **draw path as my device moves**.
Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean as your device move? either way you have to get location updates using location listener and on every new update create a Polyline between the coordinates of the new update and the previous one.

**UPDATE**: Here are some post that show you how to draw a polyline with direction:

[Is there a way to show road directions in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554078/is-there-a-way-to-show-road-directions-in-google-map-api-v2)

[Get driving directions using Google Maps API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495030/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-directions/15053901#15053901)

I could use the concepts there to draw you the line you want.

Comment: As location of device change

Comment: @user775 This is what he discribed. Use a `LocationListener` to see when the location of the device changes. Check the Developer Page for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: Can you guide me with some tutorial where path is drawn with polyline

Comment: I am adding 2 post that describe how to show direction on google map V2, i think you can take some ideas from there, see updated answer.