# google maps routing api V2 android

Tags: android, api, routes, maps

I have includet google map in my android program. But in the tutorial about the GM android api V2 isn`t a decription about the routing and how i can add my own created google map.

Does anybody know a tutorial for this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to show a route in my map and my map should be my own created map with my markers.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at a resembling question I asked not long ago:

[Is there a way to show road directions in Google Map API v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554078/is-there-a-way-to-show-road-directions-in-google-map-api-v2)

What you should do is:

1.Take this code I was given by @Akexorcist:

```
    package app.akexorcist.googlemapsv2direction;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class GMapV2Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public GMapV2Direction() { }

public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
}
```

2.Next, Create an asyncTask for getting the direction:

```
package com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.asynctasks;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Map;

  import org.w3c.dom.Document;

  import com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.R;
  import com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.activities.LoginScrActivity;
  import com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.activities.MapFragmentActivity;
  import com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.objects.DataAccessManager;
  import com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.objects.DialogUtils;
  import com.emildesign.sgtaskmanager.objects.GMapV2Direction;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


  import android.app.Dialog;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.widget.Toast;

   public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Object,   ArrayList<LatLng>> {

public static final String USER_CURRENT_LAT = "user_current_lat";
public static final String USER_CURRENT_LONG = "user_current_long";
public static final String DESTINATION_LAT = "destination_lat";
public static final String DESTINATION_LONG = "destination_long";
public static final String DIRECTIONS_MODE = "directions_mode";
private MapFragmentActivity activity;
private String url;

private Exception exception;

private Dialog progressDialog;

public GetDirectionsAsyncTask(MapFragmentActivity activity /*String url*/) 
{
    super();
    this.activity = activity;

    //  this.url = url;
}

public void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = DialogUtils.createProgressDialog(activity, activity.getString(R.string.get_data_dialog_message));
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if (exception == null) {
        activity.handleGetDirectionsResult(result);
    } else {
        processException();
    }
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params) {

    Map<String, String> paramMap = params[0];
    try{
        LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(USER_CURRENT_LONG)));
        LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LAT)) , Double.valueOf(paramMap.get(DESTINATION_LONG)));
        GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, paramMap.get(DIRECTIONS_MODE));
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints = md.getDirection(doc);
        return directionPoints;

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

private void processException() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, activity.getString(R.string.error_when_retrieving_data), 3000).show();
}

}
```

3.Create this two methods in your map activity for getting the direction and handling result:

```
public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoints)
{
    Polyline newPolyline;
    GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoints.size() ; i++) 
    {          
        rectLine.add(directionPoints.get(i));
    }
    newPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}


public void findDirections(double fromPositionDoubleLat, double fromPositionDoubleLong, double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
{
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LAT, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.USER_CURRENT_LONG, String.valueOf(fromPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LAT, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DESTINATION_LONG, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong));
    map.put(GetDirectionsAsyncTask.DIRECTIONS_MODE, mode);

    GetDirectionsAsyncTask asyncTask = new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(this);
    asyncTask.execute(map); 
}
```

and finally, run the find direction method:

```
findDirections(SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude(),
                                               SGTasksListAppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude(),
                                               clickMarkerLatLng.latitude, clickMarkerLatLng.longitude, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
```