# Android. Volley: SYNC http requests from "out-of-box"?

Tags: android, android-volley

Android Studio 2.3.3, Volley 1.0.0

I work with Volley to do async http requests. And it does it well from "out-of-box". OK.

But sometimes I need to do SYNC http request. And I can't found this in Volley from "out-of-box".

The question is:
Is it possible to do sync http request by Volley from "out-of-box"?

P.S. I wan't to do some workarounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Wait for volley response to return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833977/android-wait-for-volley-response-to-return)

Comment: or [Is there Any way To hold Volley request until the response Completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359974/is-there-any-way-to-hold-volley-request-until-the-response-completed)