# Android - Volley RequestFuture Timeout

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I'm experiencing a problem when using the **RequestFuture** class of volley.
Actually it just stops at `wait(0)`; inside the `doGet()` Function in the RequestFuture class below and is never getting woken up by `onResponse` or `onErrorResponse` as I think it should.

```
private synchronized T doGet(Long timeoutMs)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    if (mException != null) {
        throw new ExecutionException(mException);
    }

    if (mResultReceived) {
        return mResult;
    }

    if (timeoutMs == null) {
        wait(0);
    } else if (timeoutMs > 0) {
        wait(timeoutMs);
    }

    if (mException != null) {
        throw new ExecutionException(mException);
    }

    if (!mResultReceived) {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }

    return mResult;
}

@Override
public boolean isCancelled() {
    if (mRequest == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return mRequest.isCanceled();
}

@Override
public synchronized boolean isDone() {
    return mResultReceived || mException != null || isCancelled();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResponse(T response) {
    mResultReceived = true;
    mResult = response;
    notifyAll();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mException = error;
    notifyAll();
}
```

This is the way i try to call all this above.

```
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest myReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObj, future, future);
    requestQueue.add(myReq);

    try {

        JSONObject response = future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // handle the error
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // handle the error
    }
```

I also tried replacing the line

`requestQueue.add(myReq);`

with

`future.setRequest(requestQueue.add(myReq));`

or

`future.setRequest(myReq);`

which didn't help either.

I already tried a usual Volley Request which worked just fine using this parameters, so that shouldn't be the cause. 
I guess the problem is, that the request is never actually executed, which is why the response listeners are never reached. Also tried `requestQueue.start()`, but didn't change a thing.

I hope I explained my problem well enough,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to use RequestFuture? Can you share your use cases?

Comment: Well problem I was facing is that i have three requests and the last of these three relies on the response of the first two requests. I already tried using different RequestQueues, but it always built all requests before starting them actually. So I never got to store the values of the first two so I could use them in the last request. My workaround at the moment is using custom event listeners to react on the responses of each request and start a new one once the one before is finished.

Comment: But you already have 2 listeners for your Volley requests: the success listener and the error listener. You can fetch you result(s) in the success listener (and maybe set some custom value in your error listeners - depending on your needs) and just launch your subsequent requests from there - the success and/or error listeners. This way, your requests are synchronous and you don't have to bother implementing RequestFuture.

Comment: okay, I'll use them. I just thought using RequestFuture would be the better/cleaner approach, but it's not working properly as it seems. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wish someone had been able to answer this.  I'm having the same issue.  Sigh.

Comment: See [@Blundell's answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23808857/1518546).

Answer (score 6):

Adding a timeout to the get method will give the ability to catch the error, if no timeout is given then it sends the error back to the main thread. So changing  `JSONObject response = future.get();` with  `JSONObject response = future.get(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` should do the trick and wrap it in a try catch for the timeout

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

JSONObject response = future.get();

Always run Future Request in seperate thread. It will not work in main thread. I am running Future Request Call in an IntentService and its working perfectly fine.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `future.get()` in another thread. Try wrapping it in an AsyncTask.

Looking at the source, it looks like `RequestQueue` kicks off a long chain of calls to load the response and which eventually end in `RequestFuture.onResponse` (which in turn calls `notifyAll` to notify the thread to stop waiting, as you mentioned). I think the problem is that `wait(0)` and the `RequestQueue` chain both run in the UI thread, so when `wait(0)` is called, the `RequestQueue` chain also waits, so `onResponse` never gets called, which is why that line just hangs (because wait(0) waits forever).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Blair's and Farhan's solutions, attaching a retry policy to the request also does the job.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(RETRY_TIME, RETRY_ATTEMPTS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```