# Volley upload progress for StringRequest

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I am using volley to upload an Image after converting it to String. Now this string could be of MBs data. Now I am planning to show a progress loader with the amount that is being uploaded. foe example: 10% .. 20% .. 30% and so on.

Currently I am using volley StringRequest's POST method.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",..
```

Is there any way to get the progress percentage via using StringRequest Or I need to make custom Request?

PS: I am new to Android development

Comment: You pretty much cannot.  At best it would be inaccurate, my suggestion is to just make it intermediate ProgressBar

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687017/how-to-maintain-progress-bar-state-when-using-volley