# Android In App Billing v3 Server Verification

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have in Google in app billing set up in my app using the IabHelper classes from the trivialdrive sample app. I can successfully purchase items, and now I'm trying to implement server side verification.

I see in Security.java that there is a verifyPurchase method.
https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/v3/src/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/Security.java

I want to replace that with a call to my server that will do the verification on the server vs on the client device. I have my endpoint set up and working.

I'm stuck at how to call my endpoint and have verifyPurchase return true or false based on the response. I currently use Volley which makes async calls. I can get my endpoint's response in Volley's success callback. But since that network call is async, I'm not sure how to return true or false in verifyPurchase based on that call's response. I'm a java n00b :)

Comment: Did you try to perform synchronous requests with Volley? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface call that in response of the async call of volley use that. Implement that interface in that class where you need your `verifyPurchase()` return. Override that interface and process the response.