# What is the most efficient way of updating UI in Volley

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-volley

lately I'm using Volley library in android.. It works fine but I was wondering about the most efficient way of updating the UI.. I have a Utils class that has all the Volley methods.. right now I pass all the Views that will be updated as parameters, but I've read that I could implement the listeners in my activity then pass them as parameters in the Utils class..

**So my question is:**

Which is more efficient and why updating the UI like this:

```
public void getSettings(final TextView exampleView) {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        final String setting = getSettingFromJSON(response);
                        exampleView.setText(setting);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {

                }
            });

    app.add(jsonRequest);
}
```

Or I declare the listeners in my activity like this :

```
    Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String setting = Utils.getSettingFromJSON(response);
            exampleView.setText(setting);
        }
    };
```

then I pass them into my utils function as parameters so the call would be like this :

```
utils.getSettings(listener);
```

instead of :

```
utils.getSettings(exampleView);
```

**Thanks In Advance :)**

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to manage passing back info from the request to your activity? This way you can separate your networking code from your activities/views. The basic idea using EventBus and Volley is the following:

- Register a class to receive some type of event, in this case probably
  the activity
- Create a method in this class to handle this event,
  `exampleView.setText(setting)`.
- Post the event to the bus, post the String or volley error in the
  Volley listeners.

For a more detailed example checkout this [blogpost](http://www.jacoboakes.com/2015/06/clean-android-networking-code-with.html) or Eventbus' github page.

Answer (score 0):

As in my question [Android/Java: how to delay return in a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602042/android-java-how-to-delay-return-in-a-method/31604258)

I also use interface listener, however, I update views in main thread, not in Utils class