# Updating TextView-Text and fill it with internet data

Tags: android

I have a Listview with textviews. On a click on the convertview, the method is called:

```
 private void getAmountFromItem() {
            String url = "http://192.168.192.200/getAmountFromItem.php?amount_id=" + amountIDTest;
            Log.e("URLUZ", "is " + url);
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

                            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                                feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                                Log.e("COUNTS", " " + feedObj.getString("count"));
                                textView.setText(feedObj.getString("count") + " count yeah");
                                textView.invalidate();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }
```

I tried to set the text within "runOnUiThread" or on "textView.post(new Runnable)... but these won't work.. Any suggestions?

Comment: the question is not clear. What is it that is not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The text is not updating..

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606450/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-updating-ui-in-volley) "solution" (best practice for updating ui object from volley)