# how to wait the volley response to finish it's work inside intentservice?

Tags: android, rss, android-volley, intentservice, android-intentservice

Working with intentservice to get the data of 7 Rss Feed links with using " Google Volley " in the background and use ResultReceiver to get the result , But I can't configure how to wait on the volley response to finish it's job to fire flag with  ResultReceiver  to display the data in the MainActivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't wait for it. You have two ways to make a network request: synchronous and asynchronous. If you use synchronous, you don't wait for result because the network call is a blocking operation.

Refer this if you want to go this direction: [Can I do a synchronous request with volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley)

If you want to make it asynchronous, you just start a request and then use your `ResultReceiver` in a `Response.Listener` callback method once the request is finished.

Refer this for the details:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Networking-with-the-Volley-Library

If you still think you should block the current thread and wait for result, you should use `CountDownLatch`. Create a background thread (you cannot block UI thread in android unless it's a separate process), init your latch with count 1 and call `await()` method. This will block your background thread till the count is 0. Once your background task is finished you call `countDown()` which will unblock your background thread and you will be able to perform your action then.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered in the [official Volley Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/volley-users/SBvZNS5w4BM/4xvcTHKkIEcJ).

Wrap the request in a RequestFuture to make a blocking call using `RequestFuture#newFuture(...);`

You can find sample code in the [Volley source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/RequestFuture.java):

```
RequestFuture<SONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
MyRequest request = new MyRequest(URL, future, future);

// If you want to be able to cancel the request:
future.setRequest(requestQueue.add(request));

// Otherwise:
requestQueue.add(request);

try {
  JSONObject response = future.get();
  // do something with response
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // handle the error
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // handle the error
}
```

Be sure to use a timeout in `future.get(...)` or else your thread will lock.