# Java Android Studio cannot send ArrayList from another class to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I try to add data from my object to ArrayList but it's not work.

This code read data from JSON and add to ArrayList in MySQLConnect.java like this.

```
    private ComputerService computerservice;
    public static ArrayList<ComputerService> computerServicesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String URL = "http://10.200.100.10/", GET_URL = "android/get_data.php";

    public MySQLConnect(){
        main = null;

    }

    public MySQLConnect(Activity mainA){
        main = mainA;
    }

    public List<ComputerService> getData(){
        String url = URL + GET_URL;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                showJSON(response);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(main, error.getMessage().toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        );

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(main.getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        return computerServicesArrayList;
    }

    public void showJSON(String response){
        String data_mysql = "";
        computerServicesArrayList.clear();
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

            for(int i=0; i < result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject collectData = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = collectData.getString("id");
                String type = collectData.getString("type");
                String address = collectData.getString("address");

                computerservice = new ComputerService(id, type, address);
                computerServicesArrayList.add(computerservice);

            }

        System.out.println("Size in class MySQLConnect");
        System.out.println(computerServicesArrayList.size());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The MainActivity.java I show computerServicesArrayList.size() like this.

```
 public static List<ComputerService> computerServicesArrayList;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mySQLConnect = new MySQLConnect(MainActivity.this);

        update();
    }


    public void update(){
        computerServicesArrayList =  mySQLConnect.getData();
        System.out.println("Size in MainActivity");
        System.out.println(computerServicesArrayList.size());
}
```

The output show like this.

```
Size in MainActivity
    0

Size in class MySQLConnect
83
```

From the code I can print computerServicesArrayList.size() the result is 83 but when I print from MainActivity why it show result 0. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the `Volley` framework/classes in detail. But it looks like you are creating an asynchronous request. So your rest-request gets send and when the response comes in your `showJSON()` method is called.

But you immediatley return the `computerServicesArrayList` result, which is empty because you don't have your response yet. This is also the reason why the print statement from your `MainActivity` is executed before the print from your `showJSON` method.

If you want to wait for the rest-response you have to do synchronous requests.

Maybe this can help you more about Volley and asyn/sync requests:

- [how to wait the volley response to finish it's work inside intentservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798972/how-to-wait-the-volley-response-to-finish-its-work-inside-intentservice)
- [Can I do a synchronous request with volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley)

But normally you would send an async-request and when you get the response you do your logic (update fields, store something in database, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Your computerServicesArrayList is populated by callback from Volley (new Response.Listener()). This population happens correctly as you have verified. But it does take some time, for the network up/down travel. When your MainActivity's call to mySQLConnect.getData() returns this round trip is not complete yet; so you get an empty list in MainActivity.

The usual solution to this problem is to make the listener call methods in MainActivity. This can be done by making

```
class MainActivity implements Response.Listener<String> {

/* --- */
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    showJSON(response);
}

void showJSON(String response){
    // Do the stuff here
}
```