# Android: How to return async JSONObject from method using Volley?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-volley

I'm trying to get back JSON object in the following way:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = http.makeRequest("GET", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json", null);
```

General method for processing all HTTP requests is following

```
public void makeRequest(String method, String url, Array params) {

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(getRequestMethod(method),
            url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    processResponse(Constants.Global.SUCCESS, null, response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    try {
                        mStatusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                        VolleyLog.d(Constants.Global.ERROR, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Logger.e(error.getMessage());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.e(e.getMessage());
                        mStatusCode = 0;
                    }
                    Logger.e(mStatusCode.toString());
                    processResponse(Constants.Global.ERROR, mStatusCode, null);
                }
            });
    // Add tag to request for bulk cancelling
    //jsonObjReq.setTag()
    queue.add(jsonObjReq);
}
```

And method for processing JSON result is following:

```
private JSONObject processResponse(String resultState, Integer httpStatusCode, JSONObject responseData) {
        try {
            // First check that result state is error or the success
            if (resultState.equals(Constants.Global.SUCCESS)) {
                Logger.i("Response is success");
                Logger.i(responseData.toString());
                //TODO: ADD SUCCESS OBJECT CREATION
            }
            if (resultState.equals(Constants.Global.ERROR)) {
                Logger.e("Response is error");
                //TODO: ADD ERROR HANDLING AND ERROR OBJECT CREATION
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Logger.e(e.getMessage());
        }
        return responseData;
    }
```

I would like to ask how can i to get back JSONObject (first code snippet) in the async way.

All requests are processed using the Volley library.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: See if your requirements like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268861/android-volley-synchronous-and-asynchronous-http-requests) or not

Comment: Thank Yopu, but I think that not, i would like to know how to do with some code example which is fit to my requirements.

Comment: Actually, I still cannot understand what does your async here mean? According to [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), it's async already (... `with data fetched asynchronously from the network.`)

Comment: I think that async is provided by Volley automatically. So i need to know how to get JSON data into the first snippet.

Comment: Does my answer work for your question?

Comment: Thanks, it looks as good solution, but i don't understand what exactly means using the MySingleton class. I need some example for this.

Comment: About the Singleton, you can refer [here - Use a Singleton Pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your comment

> I think that async is provided by Volley automatically. So i need to
>   know how to get JSON data into the first snippet

IMO, instead of your first snippet, you can try the following way (of course, you can replace `JSONArray` request by `JSONObject` request):

```
VolleyResponseListener listener = new VolleyResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                // do something...
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Object response) {
                // do something...
            }
        };

makeJsonArrayRequest(context, Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, listener);
```

Body of `makeJsonArrayRequest` can be as the following:

```
    public void makeJsonArrayRequest(Context context, int method, String url, String requestBody, final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
        JSONObject jsonRequest = null;        
        try {
            ...
            if (requestBody != null) {
                jsonRequest = new JSONObject(requestBody);
            }
            ...
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                listener.onResponse(jsonArray);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.onError(error.toString());
            }
        });

        // Access the RequestQueue through singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

`VolleyResponseListener` interface as the following:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {
    void onError(String message);

    void onResponse(Object response);
}
```