# Android : how to return JSONObject from Volley OnRequest StringRequest method

Tags: java, android, android-volley, json

i need to pass the response string by assigning value to the string data to another method out side the OnResponse() scpoe so that i can return a JSONObject from it by calling that method but it always returns null

all i need is to get JSONObject from Volley stringrequest as the response is a xml "

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">........</string>
```

Here is my code

```
static String data;

private  void driverByIdStringRequest(int ID,final Context context){
        RequestQueue queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url+ID,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        response = response.replaceAll("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "");
                        response = response.replaceAll("<string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">", "");
                        response = response.replaceAll("</string>", "");
                        String data = response.substring(40);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error : ", error.toString());
            }
        });
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }


public JSONObject GetDriverById(int ID,Context context){
    driverByIdStringRequest(ID, context);
    JSONObject json = JSONObject(data);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a JsonObjectRequest instead?

Comment: Because he receives an XML response containing a JSON

Comment: @VadimCaen: ah, I see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the String response from your StringRequest always has the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">........</string>
```

in which `........` is the `JSONObject` you want to get, I suggest that you process the String reponse like the following way:

```
...
String jsonString = stringResponse;

jsonString = jsonString.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"," ");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("<string xmlns=\"tempuri.org/\">"," ");
jsonString = jsonString.replace("</string>"," ");
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

Back to your code, `data` of course NULL because `JSONObject json = JSONObject(data);` called before `onResponse` inside the Request called. I suggest that you refer to my answer at the following question for your issue:

[Android: How to return async JSONObject from method using Volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375295/android-how-to-return-async-jsonobject-from-method-using-volley)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad it could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The best maintainable way to do it is first to parse you XML with a Parser.

Just follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) on the official doc.

Once you got your string you just have to do

`JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(Your_Sring_data);`

*(Android studio will prompt you to put the correct try/catch around the JSON creation.)*