# How to stop for loop execution until responce come in android

Tags: android

I want to add each user response to my list listItem, inserting the response's specific key and value pair.  However, in this code, the first loop of getCat() executes 4 times ... then all responses get added to the last key those are 4.

```
public void getCat(){

    String url = "http://******/*****/*****.json";
    HashMap<String, List<CatType> hmap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<CatType>>();
    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
       {

       JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
             url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
           parseJsonFeed(response);
           listItems = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
           listItem.addAll(O_listItems);
           hmap.put("["+i+"]",listItem);
       }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
       }
    });

    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
    }
}

private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("food");
        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);
            OrderListItem item=new OrderListItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setImage(feedObj.getString("image"));
            item.setItem_name(feedObj.getString("name"));
            O_listItems.add(item);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because each time you make a request a new thread is created, so before the response comes back from the first hit, a new hit is made and this goes on. For such kind of situation it is better to use AsyncTask or make synchronous hits. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley) answer for making synchronous hits.

Comment: I implementation as given link. but i am not getting where i have to receive the response from server means, where i have to pass the Json response to parseJson(JSONObject response).

Comment: JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, URL_FETCH1+categoryTemp.getId(),null, future, future) ; It 's not working

Comment: Hi Varnkr as you told I tried AsyncTask also but it not working. please help me.