# Regarding loading items to the spinner using volley library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, android-tablayout

I am trying to load items to the spinner inside my `MainActivity` toolbar.Inside `MainActivity` there is a fragment called `HomeFragment`. And that fragment contains `SlidingTabLayout` and once I click different tabs I need to load different data sets to the above mentioned spinner.

> Here is how it looks like :

[image]

I have implemented method inside `MainActivity` to add data to the spinner :

```
    public void addItemsToSpinner(final Collection<String> collection) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.addAll(collection);

        CustomSpinnerAdapter spinAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        subCategories_spinner.setAdapter(spinAdapter);
        subCategories_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected  : " + item,
//                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

And inside my `HomeActivity` I have set `OnPageChangeLister` to `SlidingTabLayout` like below :

```
mTabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (firstScrolled) {
                    // Here log-cat gives me I/Position: On page scrolled - 0 which means on stating app this line executed. But data not set to the spinner.
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page scrolled - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("women");
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);//debug console subs (ArrayList) size given as 0 here
                    firstScrolled = false;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page selected - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("women");
                   ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);

                }
                if (position == 1) {
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page selected - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("men");
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);

                }
                if (position == 2) {
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page selected - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("household%20goods");
                   ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

With use of `volleySubCatFilter("category_here");` method I retrieve data from volley request to the server and it is working fine.

The problem I have is first time loading the application **WOMEN** tab is selected and but no data loaded to the spinner.But I tried with `Log.i("Position", "On page scrolled - " + position);` and as soon as the app loaded it gives me `I/Position: On page scrolled - 0` in my log-cat.But data doesnt load.
Debuging line `((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs)` tells 0 items.Once I press another tab then it starts loading data which belongs to previous tab. Example :- Pressing **MEN** tab right after app loaded getting data belongs to **WOMEN** tab.Then I click on any tab it start loading data belongs to **WOMEN** tab.

> If I brief this problem data loading to the spinner is one step
>   behind.

[image]

It would be grateful if anyone suggest me a way to get rid of this bug.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the sequential steps as your data is being loaded in the `background thread`. When you select a page, you have two options.

**1. Initiate either a `Synchronous Volley call`and update the spinner adapter after this call**

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null, future, future);
requestQueue.add(request);

try {
  JSONObject response = future.get(); // this will block (forever)
  ArrayList<String> some_items = response.getStringArray();
  //update the spinner with new items

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // exception handling
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // exception handling
}
```

**2. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` and then `sendBroadcast` through `LocalBroadcastManager` on `VolleyResponse`. and update the spinner items in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver**

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should cite the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17035421/208273) of that code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's a bug or feature that initially **pagechangelistener** is not being called in case of app start-up. It gets called once you switch the tab. I would like you to make some changes in the code:

Write the functionality you wish to perform in a method in the Activity and then call this in the onPageSelected method.

```
mTabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int index) {
        if (position == 0) {
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page selected - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("women");
                   ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);

                }
                if (position == 1) {
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page selected - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("men");
                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);

                }
                if (position == 2) {
                   // Log.i("Position", "On page selected - " + position);
                    volleySubCatFilter("household%20goods");
                   ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);

                }
    }
    ...
}
```

And then right after calling

```
setCurrentItem(index);
```

in the Activity, add the following if statement

```
if(index == 0) {
    volleySubCatFilter("women");
                       ((MainActivity) getActivity()).addItemsToSpinner(subs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through following steps :

1. Create an interface :

`public interface Updateable {
    public void update();
}`

2. implement above interface in your ViewPager Fragments.
3. In your PagerAdapter class, override the `getItemPosition(Object object)`

`public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

```
    if (object instanceof ManFragment) {
        ManFragment f = (ManFragment) object;
        f.update();
    } else if (object instanceof WomanFragment) {
        WomanFragment f = (WomanFragment) object;
        f.update();
    }
    else if (object instanceof HouseFragment) {
        HouseFragment f = (HouseFragment) object;
        f.update();
    }

    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}`
```

4. Now in your fragment's update() method, provide the logic for updating the spinner data in toolbar. It can be done by providing the `invalidateOptionMenu()` in update method and `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in OncreateView of your fragment. Toolbar spinner data updation can be done by implementing `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` override method.
5. In you tabs page scroll logic, notify the adapter :

`@Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                 yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }`