# Android: TabLayout in Activity, ViewPager in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager

I have the following problem:
I am using a navigation drawer in the MainActivity so this is why I use Fragments.

Some Fragments need Tabs, so I inserted a TabLayout in the AppBarLayout below the Toolbar in the MainActivity.

When using a ViewPager in the Fragment and calling `mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager` everything works, but only one time. How to setup the TabLayout several times?

Comment: do you want to update the data of fragments provided in ViewPager?

Comment: I have an Activity with the TabLayout and a FrameLayout which I use to replace with Fragments. Some of these fragments contain ViewPager which I want to connect with the TabLayout. But this can only be done one time

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35693193/1944782, for connecting the updating the fragments inside the viewpager.

Comment: The question is not very clear