# Using Volley with Sync Adapter

Tags: android, multithreading, android-volley, android-syncadapter

I've searched a lot about this but can't find any solution. I have been using **Volley** for a long time to handle my network communication. Recently I decided to use a `SyncAdapter` to sync my data to the server. Inside the `onPerformSync()` method, I thought I'll use Volley to send the data to the server as its very easy with Volley to make GET, POST requests.

**Problem** - `SyncAdapter` and Volley both use their own seperate threads. So when I initiate a Volley request from inside the `onPerformSync()` method, the `SyncAdapter` does not wait for the Volley request to complete and finishes the sync before the `onResponse()` or `onErrorResponse()` callback of Volley is received. I need to make further network calls inside the `SyncAdapter` after first call returns successfully.

**Example Code** -

```
@Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
                              ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

        JsonObjectRequest jReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, url, data,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "response = " + response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "error = " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jReq);  

    //onPerformSync() exits before request finished   
    }
```

**Question** - So how do I make the `SyncAdapter` to wait until the network response is received by Volley?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a synchronous volley request.

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, null, future, future);
requestQueue.add(request);
```

and then use:

```
try {
  JSONObject response = future.get(); // this will block (forever)
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // exception handling
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // exception handling
}
```

Code from: [Can I do a synchronous request with volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley)