# The value of the Boolean check is null at "return check"

Tags: php, android, boolean, localhost, android-volley

I am using volley connection in local host and have a php file in the local host. Below is my class VolleyConnectionLogin and I have also a volley singleton class(which has no error)..

```
public class VolleyConnectionLogin {

    Context context;
    public VolleyConnectionLogin(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    static Boolean check;
    public Boolean volleyConnection(final String username , final String password) {
        String tag_string_req = "string_req";
        String url = "http://192.168.10.8/login/forlogin.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        if(response.toString().equals("successful")){
                            check = true;
                        }else{
                            check = false;
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                check = false;
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("uname", username);
                params.put("pword", password);
                return params;
            }

        };
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        return check;
    }
}
```

Comment: `check` variable is always false because you are setting the value  of `check` variable in the `onResponse` method which is callback method.

Comment: intialize check with false like this  `static Boolean check=false;` because default value of `Boolean` type is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

`check` is null because the request is `asynchronous`, so when the following line is called

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

the program then proceeds to the next line which is

```
return check; // (which is still null)
```

while another thread in the background started processing the request.

You could [modify the request to be `synchronous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley) or modify your code so that whatever you have depending on the return of this method happens in the `onResponse()` block in the `Response.Listener` callback instead.

Answer (score 1):

since you are returning boolean outside of your thread in which it receives response, this one

```
 Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        if(response.toString().equals("successful")){
                            check = true;
                        }else{
                            check = false;
                        }
                    }
```

control goes to `return check;` before the response return.