# Creating an authentication manager with Android

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley, basic-authentication

**Task**
Create a one-time login feature using Android's authentication manager.

**Current Process**
I am currently using the Volley to read email and password from a form and send a request to a server

**Required Change**
To be able to create a one-time login for the use with credentials, using Android authentication manager following this [post](https://www.fussylogic.co.uk/blog/?p=1031).

**Question**
1. My question lies in the implementation of the `fetchTokenFromCredentials` method under the `getAuthToken` of the authenticator class.

Here is the Java code snippet:

```java
@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options)
throws NetworkErrorException {

    // We can add rejection of a request for a token type we
    // don't support here
    // Get the instance of the AccountManager that's making the
    // request
    final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);

    // See if there is already an authentication token stored
    String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

    // If we have no token, use the account credentials to fetch
    // a new one, effectively another logon
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        final String password = am.getPassword(account);
        if (password != null) {
            authToken = fetchTokenFromCredentials(account.name, password, authTokenType)
        }
    }

    // If we either got a cached token, or fetched a new one, hand
    // it back to the client that called us.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
        return result;
    }

    // If we get here, then we don't have a token, and we don't have
    // a password that will let us get a new one (or we weren't able
    // to use the password we do have).  We need to fetch
    // information from the user, we do that by creating an Intent
    // to an Activity child class.
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);

    // We want to give the Activity the information we want it to
    // return to the AccountManager.  We'll cover that with the
    // KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE parameter.
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    // We'll also give it the parameters we've already looked up, or
    // were given.
    intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, false);
    intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);

    // Remember that we have to return a Bundle, not an Intent, but
    // we can tell the caller to run our intent to get its
    // information with the KEY_INTENT parameter in the returned
    // Bundle
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

Previously I was using Volley , so my implementation of `fetchTokenfromCredentials` was something like shown below. However, I cannot use the same implementation now because I need to 'return' an authentication string. Volley does the login asynchronously so even if i add a return type to the function below it will always return null. Question: How do i wrap around THIS situation. What alternatives can I use?

```java
public void fetchTokenfromCredentials(String name, String password) {
    JSONObject loginObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        loginObject.put("email", email);
        loginObject.put("password", password);
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // assume predefined url and params
    JsonObjectRequest loginRequest = new HeaderRequest(Request.Method.POST, url + params, loginObject, new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONObject headers = response.getJSONObject("headers");
                // A simple use class that stores the id, username etc.
                user = new User(response.getInt("id"), response.getString("name"), response.getString("authentication_token"), response.getString("email"));
                // Previous code started a new main activity intent here
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {@Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed response");
        }
    });
    RequestQueueSingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(loginRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I wrote the fetchTokensFromCredentials(email,password) function using the android Http Client Library:

URL was created using a uri builder

```
Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(AccountGeneral.LOGIN_QUERY).buildUpon()
        .build();
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Stores result of the post response
        String result = null;

        // Create a JSON object for the email and password
        JSONObject loginObject = new JSONObject();
        try{
            loginObject.put("email", email);
            loginObject.put("password", password);
        } catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Convert JSON to String
        String data = loginObject.toString();

        // Connection parameters
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        try {

            //Start POST request - Write
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Read response
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();

            return result;

        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a synchronous, blocking request with Volley. That request will perform the network request, while blocking the thread and allow you to set a return type.

I am not fluent with Volley (Retrofit, FTW!) but I am pretty sure it's doable.

Take a look at this answer for a Synchronous request - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23808857