# Thread.join is not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I want to execute the following threads, and wait for them to finish in order to continue working, However, this is not achieved through my code and I don't know why, I suppose join should force the current thread to wait for all threads to finish!.
I would be pleased if anyone could help me!

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<Thread> retrievalThreads=new ArrayList<Thread>();

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getProfilePictures(false);
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getNumVotesThisWeek();
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add( new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getTotalVotes(true);
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getTotalMatches();
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getUserActivityLevel();
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getUserMatchMakerLevel();
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getLastBoostTimeStamp(true);
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getLastStealTimeStamp(true);
        }
    }));

    retrievalThreads.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getFacebookFriends();
        }
    }));

    //Start all above threads
    for (int i=0;i<retrievalThreads.size();i++)
        retrievalThreads.get(i).start();

    //Wait for them to finish
    for (int i=0;i<retrievalThreads.size();i++){
        try {
            retrievalThreads.get(i).join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.i("Finished","TheAbove");
```

The printing in the Log Console is done before threads finish execution!

Comment: Yes, calling `join` will  force the current thread to wait for all threads in `retrievalThreads` finish. And the code you posted is fine. Can you post more details? The "Log Console is done" before which method?

Comment: Printing is done before all threads finish @user6690200 , as if I didn't call join()

Comment: I understand. But the code you post seems ok. Can you post more details?

Comment: details like what ? :D

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @user6690200 the methods I'm executing inside the run() method are volley requests

Comment: The code you have provided here looks fine.  If you put a log message in each of your threads at the end of their run methods, you will see that join is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.join()` will wait only for the thread which creates volley reuqest, not all threads. Volley will spawn other threads to send the request asynchronously. You need [synchronous volley requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley).