# JSON get address by coordinates

Tags: java, android, json, android-gps

I create an application for Android, which saves GPS coordinates and displays them with addresses.

I have a function:

```
public String getAddressByGpsCoordinates(String latlan) {

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    String url=  "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latlan+"&sensor=true&key=(I have a correct key :))";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
    return address;
}
```

It is returned NULL all the time.
Can You help me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JsonObjectRequest` with a `RequestQueue` is an asynchronous mechanism--the work is performed in the background and the `onResponse` callback is called whenever the response is ready.

Because of this, it is very likely that you return from your method before `onResponse` gets called, and since `address` isn't set beforehand (that you've shown, anyway), its value will be `null`.

If you want to block your thread until the request has completed and set the value of `address`, you should use a `RequestFuture`: [Can I do a synchronous request with volley?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904741/can-i-do-a-synchronous-request-with-volley)