# How to find direction using Longitude and Latitude points in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-location, locationmanager

I am new to android.In my program i have used **Location manager** to find latitude and longitude of two points A(lat1,long1) and B(lat2,long2). Now i have to find direction of point A from point B(For example: point A lies in **North** of point B ).Please suggest a way to find the direction.
ps:I am not using google maps API in my app.

Comment: Did you looking at this example? https://www.sunearthtools.com/tools/distance.php#txtDist_3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502795/get-direction-compass-with-two-longitude-latitude-points

check this.

Comment: Please check the below link > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916679/google-maps-android-v2-and-direction-api/43089555#43089555